# property template for c++/CX

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, c++-cx

When writing C++/CX code, intended to bind to XAML, the following pattern keeps occuring:

```
public ref class NoteViewModel sealed
{

public:

    property NoteList^ List
    {
        NoteList^ get()
        {
            if ( !_List )
            {
                _List = ref new NoteList();
            }
            return _List;
        }
    }

private:

    NoteList^ _List;

};
```

Not only must a handle be used for the member `NoteList^ _List`, we also need the property and get() for 'bind compatibility'. A nice feature is that `_List` is constructed automatically, if get() occurs.

Question 1: Is there a simpler way to set this up, without hats and ref new?

Question 2: If it has to be this way, is there a clever (template) way to reduce verbosity?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Question #1, it isn't always the case that a property you create on a ViewModel will always have a backing store. Especially for readonly properties, it might just be the result of inspecting values on an underlying model or embedded object, or just a combination of other properties on the viewmodel. But you do often need a backing store.

Which leads to Question #2: I have not seen a good template-based solution, as generally speaking anything that has a template type can't be public due to WinRT rules. I've seen patterns using C Macros to generate common property patterns where it's a trivial getter/setter with backing store and usually implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

**Hypothesis A**
Standard C++ class templates and the {^, ref new} syntax/semantics of WinRT components will be entirely incompatible with each other.  (I.e., standard C++ by definition of course does not have the proprietary /CX component extensions.)  So no hope there.

**Hypothesis B**
Generics in component extensions will not come to the rescue either because the backing-store member-datum is private and because there is no way to pass in a name as identifier to utilize (e.g., {List, _List} in your example) as boilerplate.  Generics are not macros, even when conceptualized as mixin interfaces.

**Hypothesis C**
That leaves C macros as the remaining potential solution, as out-of-vogue as they are.  There are actually 2 approaches to utilizing macros:

1. put the code to be expanded in a macro, taking the aforementioned
   identifier as a parameter of the macro.
2. put the code to be expanded in a file, #define the aforementioned
   type and identifier as macros to be passed into the file, and then #include
   that file.

**Solution C.1:**

```
#define CX_PROPERTY( TYPE_CX_, IDENTIFIER_ ) \
public: property TYPE_CX_ ^ IDENTIFIER_ \
    { \
    TYPE_CX_ ^ get() \
        { \
        if( !_##IDENTIFIER_ ) \
            _##IDENTIFIER_ = ref new TYPEC_CX(); \
        return _##IDENTIFIER; \
        } \
    } \
private: TYPE_CX ^ _##IDENTIFIER_;
```

Then expand it as:

```
public ref class NoteViewModel sealed
  {
  CX_PROPERTY( NoteList, List )
  }
```

**Solution C.2**

```
public ref class NoteViewModel sealed
    {
#   define TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE       NoteList
#   define TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER    List
#   include <cxProperty.TEMPLATE.def>
    {;
```

Then in a separate file named cxProperty.TEMPLATE.def that is located somewhere along your /I include-file-directories path:

```
#if !defined TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE
#    error "You forgot to #define TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE"
#endif
#if !defined TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER
#    error "You forgot to #define TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER
#endif
public: property TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE ^ TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER
    {
    TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE ^ get()
        {
            if( !_##TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER )
                _##TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER = ref new TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE();
            return _##TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER;
        }
    }
private: TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE ^ _##TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER;

#undef TEMPLATE_PARAM_CX_TYPE
#undef TEMPLATE_PARAM_IDENTIFIER
```

By the way, absolutely do not put #pragma once or the old-school #if/#ifdef header multiple-inclusion protection guards into cxProperty.TEMPLATE.def, because you will actually want to be including this file more than once, generating a different property at each #include of the same cxProperty.TEMPLATE.def file.